# Update one row based off distinct values of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a data set with post codes, suburbs and their longitude and latitude.

For each postcode there are multiple rows with the corresponding suburbs within that postcode, so when I match it with another table which has sales by postcode in Power BI I end up with multiple rows returned for each post code.

What I'd like to do is insert a column called unique_postcode as a boolean marking one line of each post code as True. I don't mind which one. I tried the below as well as a few other options, it didn't give any errors but didn't have any affect.

```
UPDATE postcodes
SET post_codes.unique_postcode = 1
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT(postcode)
    FROM postcodes
);
```

Comment: You can use `row_number` as shown in the answers or use `not exists` if your table has an id (e.g. update all rows where not exists a row with a lower ID for the postcode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an updatable CTE which targets a random row:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY postcode ORDER BY postcode) rn
    FROM postcodes
)

UPDATE cte
SET unique_postcode = 1
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Note that because the ordering used in `ROW_NUMBER` uses the postal code itself, the "first" row number value could be any of the rows, in the case that a postal code have more than one record associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` to define a particular one to assign the flag to.  In an update, this looks like:

```
WITH toupdate AS (
      SELECT p.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY postcode ORDER BY postcode) as seqnum
      FROM postcodes p
     )
UPDATE toupdate
    SET unique_postcode = (CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
```

Note:  This sets one value to "1" and the rest to "0".  It is also safe to run multiple times on the table.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I'm not sure what was wrong, there was no error message but it also didn't have any affect.

Comment: @PaulClarke . . . You should have gotten an error that `seqnum` was undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If the row doesn't matter then the simplest way would be to select TOP 1.

```
with cte as (select top 1 * from postcodes)
update cte
set unique_postcode = 1;
```